# How do I do Hibernate style Embeddable Classes in .NET Core?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, angular5

We are using .NET Core and want to do [Hibernate style Embeddable Classes](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/embeddable-classes/).

For example, we have Object A which contains Address fields (addr1, addr2, city, state, zip) which we would like to return with a pseudo object(pseudoaddress) which is a composite object of the address fields along with a concatenation of all address fields and some helper methods. However, we wish to send Object A back to the controller so the object would be recognized by our PUT & POST in the controller.

How do we implement this style in a generic, reusable way?

Answer (score 0):

In EntityFramework Core 2.0, this feature was intruded as "owned entities".

See [New features in EF Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/index), section "Owned types" for more details.